# Installation Fails on Live Website

Tags: install

I have installed Craft 2.2.2579 on my never-before-used website live rather than on my PC in a development environment. (I am not a developer.) Instructions were followed exactly (I believe), but when I point my browser to http://{mySiteName}/admin or the other alternatives, I get:
[image: Error Message]

The index page of the website itself loads just fine as http://{mySiteName}.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you so much, Lindsey D and Brad Bell. It looked right, but I re-copied from original file using Sublime Text, and the next thing you know, voila! Because it looked right (hidden characters? - what did I do?), I would have been a much longer time thinking to just redo it. Two thumbs up, especially for taking the time to answer such a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up this file:

```
/craft/config/db.php
```

... and take a look at the very first line. The file **should** start with this:

```
<?php
```

It sounds like that may not be the case with your file. Make sure there is absolutely nothing before that `<` character, not even a blank line.

Comment: 100 monopoly dollars says this is it.